# Can a person see other files in the s3 bucket if the s3 bucket has given public access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can a person see other files in the s3 bucket if the s3 bucket has given public access?

Also he have a link to one of the files in the s3 bucket.

Comment: It depends on what the "public access" is. If it's `s3:GetObject` to `*`, then everyone in the world can download it.

Comment: What do you mean by "bucket has given public access"? How has this been given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default. Nobody can view a listing of the bucket, nor the objects within the bucket, unless you have granted access in some way.

The typical mechanism for "making a bucket public" is to add a **Bucket Policy** that can grant permission to perform operations such as `GetObject`, `PutObject` and `ListBucket`. You should look at your Bucket Policy to determine what permissions have been granted.

If the Bucket Policy grants `ListBucket` permissions to *anyone* (`Principal = *`), then they *would* be able to view a list of all objects in the bucket. This is normally not recommended.